# is there anyway to have an <hr> under text with no vertical space

Tags: html, css

is there anyway to have text and then a

```
<hr>
```

where the

```
<hr>
```

line is directly under the text and doesn't have any vertical space in between the text and the line?

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/7FWu8/) ?

Comment: What browsers are you testing in? This is trivial in modern browsers, but some older versions of IE make this tricky.

Comment: @thirtydot - i am testing in firefox but i need to support IE8

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
<styles>
  hr{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
  }
</styles>
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Just shift it with css. Example:

```
<p>text goes here</p>
<hr style='margin-top:-1em' />
```

This will have no vertical space between them

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I've used a zero-height bordered div to give this finer-grained formatting control; or to show a horizontal rule that has a different appearance from a straight <hr>.

Answer (score 0):

`hr`'s are/were notoriously difficult to style consistently across browsers as they use different properties, `color`, `background-color`, `border` etc. to constitute their parts,

however if it's just IE8 support you're after then [see this example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/ZkwZu/)

that has everything but the kitchen sink thrown at it, <strike>and still it doesn't work in IE7</strike>

this makes it work in IE7 too :

```
hr {margin: -7px 0 !ie7;}
```

my method has always been to do the following (warning it's yukky but does provide a lot of styling opportunities!):

```
<div class="hr"><hr></div>
```

with whatever styles needed applied to `div.hr {styles}` and `.hr hr {display: none;}`

this means the actual `hr` will still show in non-CSS/Text browsers, and I can still style the actual div with images or borders without having to remember the *kitchen sink* method in the JSFiddle example linked above ;) YMMV though..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/simple-styles-for-horizontal-rules/) are a few examples of css for hr-Elements and also as the eighth example the solution of how to write text in the middle of a line without a break before and after it. This is the code:

HTML:

```
<!-- Glyph, by Harry Roberts -->
<hr class="style-eight">
```

CSS:

```
hr.style-eight {
margin: 0 auto 24px;
padding: 0;
border: none;
border-top: medium double #333;
color: #333;
text-align: center; }

hr.style-eight:after {
content: "§";
display: inline-block;
position: relative; 
top: -0.97em;  
font-size: 1.5em;
padding: 0.25em;
background: white;}
```